# ANTLR3's stateful lexer fails on Unicode characters on C target

Tags: c, antlr

I have an ANTLR3 grammar with relevant parts like these:

```
TOK_CODE_BEGIN : {!inCode}?=> '{{' { inCode = true; };
TOK_TEXT : {!inCode}?=> (~'{')* | '{';

TOK_CODE_END : '}}' { inCode = false; };

TOK_STRING : {inCode}?=> '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"';

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : {inCode}?=> ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ : {inCode}?=>
        '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC : {inCode}?=> '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT;
```

I try to feed it the following UTF-8-encoded input:

```
"Hello, world!" - {{"Hello, world!"}}
"Hello,\t\tworld!" - {{"Hello,\t\tworld!"}}
"\u041F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, \u043C\u0438\u0440!" - {{"\u041F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, \u043C\u0438\u0440!"}}
"Привет, мир!" - {{"Привет, мир!"}}
```

On the Java target, it works like a charm. The straightforward C target port of the grammar, however, gives me the following error:

```
expression(4): lexer error 6 :
    !ctx->inCode at offset 20, near '"' :
```

I modified the error display function to throw an exception, so I can't really tell if there are any errors beyond this. I'm using the 64-bit version of ANTLR3 C runtime.

---

What does it all mean? **Is there a way to fix this issue?** On a tangental note, does ANTLR3 support lexer multiplexing so that I could refactor my grammar into two (I suspect it will drastically reduce the lexer's size)?

Comment: Have you already tried the suggestion in http://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2012-July/044918.html?

Comment: @Jongware I run 3.5.1, and I do use UTF8 encoding in the input stream.

Comment: @Jongware I recompiled with 3.4 (both ANTLR itself and its C runtime), same thing.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko What rule parses the Cyrillic characters?

Comment: @o_weisman, TOK_TEXT gobbles them up nicely.